# Content Security Policy issue when using JS files with firefox-addon

Tags: javascript, html, json, firefox-addon

I'm making a browser extension and am getting this error when loading the add-on in firefox:

```
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at self (“script-src”). Source: onclick attribute on SPAN element.index.html
```

I've narrowed down the problem to when I call javascript methods in the html. It doesn't seem to be a problem for digitalClock.js, only things like onclick="foo()" gives me the error for each onclick I have.

```js
//settings.js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySettings").style.width = "325px";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySettings").style.width = "0";
}
//digitalClock.js is working. The error message occurs even if this is removed.
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/clock.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/settings.css" />
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Title</title>
</head>

<span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span>

<div id="myClock" class="clock">clock</div>

<script src=scripts/digitalClock.js></script>
<script src=scripts/settings.js></script>

</html>
```

manifest.json

```
{

  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "CPS error",
  "version": "1.0",

  "description": "CPS error",

  "icons": {
    "48": "icons/border-48.png"
  },


  "permissions": ["storage", "tabs","geolocation"],


  "chrome_settings_overrides": {
    "homepage": "public/index.html"
  },
  "chrome_url_overrides": {
    "newtab": "public/index.html"
    }
}
```

If I remove the line:

```
<span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span>
```

the add-on will load without issue. If I could get some help with this error message it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly, you shouldn't call javascript methods in the html, but move the JS logic in the JS.

For example you could remove your onclick, add an id="nav" to your span and then use a JS listener:

```
document.getElementById("nav").addEventListener("click", function(){
  openNav();
});
```

This should remove the warning.